# Animation Reverse not working - CSS3

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm just trying out on the CSS3 animations.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZpGObE?editors=0110

I add and remove the class on a image container and calling `animation-direction: reverse;` which is currently not working.

**Edit:**

I'm toggling the class `open` and `close` with a animation being calling on the image tag namely `animation` the keyframe name.

What's happening is, when the `open` class is added, the image pops up with a the animation that is being called. And when the `close` class is added, I'm calling the `animation: reverse;` which is not working currently.

Below the code I'm using.

```
.image-container {
    height: 128px;
    width: 128px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;

    img {
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

    &.open,
    &.close {
        img {
            -webkit-animation: animation;
            animation: animation;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
            animation-duration: 1s;
            -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
            animation-fill-mode: both;
            -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
            animation-timing-function: linear;
        }   
    }

    &.close {
        img {
            -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
            animation-direction: reverse;
        }
    }
}
```

Help me out to find where I'm doing the mistake.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Explain what exactly is not working correctly and than the community can help you. I see you append the image to the body, you want to make a duplication every time you press the button?

Comment: Hope the question is clear now.

Comment: @DerkJanSpeelman - I'm not removing the element currently. I just wanted the image to go off with a reverse animation when the class `close` is added.

Answer (score 0):

It works when you add `animation` to `.close` and not to `.close img`.

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    var $html = $('<div class="image-container open">' +
      '<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/APMNs.jpg" alt="" />' +
      '</div>')

    $('body')
      .append($html);

    if ($('.image-container').length) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.image-container').removeClass('open');
        $('.image-container').addClass('close');
      }, 3000);
    }
  })
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #333;
}
body .image-container {
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
body .image-container img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
body .image-container.open img {
  -webkit-animation: animation;
  animation: animation;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
body .image-container.close {
  -webkit-animation: animation;
  animation: animation;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}
 

@-webkit-keyframes animation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  2.083333% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.75266, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.76342, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.75266, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.76342, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  4.166667% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.81071, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.84545, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.81071, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.84545, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  6.25% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.86808, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.9286, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.86808, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.9286, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  8.333333% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.92038, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.92038, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  10.416667% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.96482, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.05202, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.96482, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.05202, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  12.5% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.08204, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.08204, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  14.583333% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.02563, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.09149, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.02563, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.09149, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  16.666667% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.04227, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.08453, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.04227, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.08453, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  18.75% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.05102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.06666, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.05102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.06666, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  20.833333% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.05334, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.04355, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.05334, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.04355, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  22.916667% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.05078, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.02012, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.05078, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.02012, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.04487, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.04487, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  27.083333% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.03699, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.98534, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.03699, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.98534, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  29.166667% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.02831, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.97688, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.02831, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.97688, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  31.25% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.01973, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.97422, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.01973, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.97422, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  33.333333% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.01191, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.97618, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.01191, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.97618, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  35.416667% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.00526, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.98122, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.00526, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.98122, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  37.5% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.98773, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.98773, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  39.583333% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.99617, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99433, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.99617, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99433, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  41.666667% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.99368, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.99368, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  43.75% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.99237, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00413, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.99237, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00413, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  45.833333% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.99202, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00651, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.99202, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00651, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  47.916667% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.99241, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00726, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.99241, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00726, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.99329, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00671, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.99329, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00671, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  52.083333% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.99447, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00529, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.99447, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00529, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  54.166667% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.99577, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00346, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.99577, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00346, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  56.25% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.99705, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0016, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.99705, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0016, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  58.333333% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.99822, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.99822, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  60.416667% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.99921, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99884, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.99921, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99884, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  62.5% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99816, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99816, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  64.583333% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.00057, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99795, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.00057, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99795, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  66.666667% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.00095, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99811, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.00095, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99811, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  68.75% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.00114, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99851, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.00114, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99851, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  70.833333% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.00119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99903, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.00119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99903, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  72.916667% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.00114, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99955, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.00114, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99955, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.001, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.001, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  77.083333% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.00083, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00033, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.00083, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00033, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  79.166667% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.00063, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00052, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.00063, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00052, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  81.25% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.00044, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00058, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.00044, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00058, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  83.333333% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.00027, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00053, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.00027, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00053, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  85.416667% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.00012, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00042, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.00012, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00042, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  87.5% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00027, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00027, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  89.583333% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.99991, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00013, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.99991, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00013, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  91.666667% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.99986, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.99986, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  93.75% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.99983, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99991, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.99983, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99991, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  95.833333% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.99982, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99985, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.99982, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99985, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  97.916667% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.99983, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99984, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.99983, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99984, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
}
@keyframes animation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  2.083333% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.75266, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.76342, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.75266, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.76342, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  4.166667% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.81071, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.84545, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.81071, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.84545, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  6.25% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.86808, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.9286, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.86808, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.9286, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  8.333333% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.92038, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.92038, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  10.416667% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.96482, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.05202, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.96482, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.05202, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  12.5% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.08204, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.08204, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  14.583333% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.02563, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.09149, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.02563, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.09149, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  16.666667% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.04227, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.08453, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.04227, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.08453, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  18.75% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.05102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.06666, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.05102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.06666, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  20.833333% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.05334, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.04355, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.05334, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.04355, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  22.916667% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.05078, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.02012, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.05078, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.02012, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.04487, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.04487, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  27.083333% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.03699, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.98534, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.03699, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.98534, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  29.166667% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.02831, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.97688, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.02831, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.97688, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  31.25% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.01973, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.97422, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.01973, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.97422, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  33.333333% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.01191, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.97618, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.01191, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.97618, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  35.416667% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.00526, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.98122, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.00526, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.98122, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  37.5% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.98773, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.98773, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  39.583333% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.99617, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99433, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.99617, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99433, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  41.666667% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.99368, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.99368, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  43.75% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.99237, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00413, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.99237, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00413, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  45.833333% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.99202, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00651, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.99202, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00651, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  47.916667% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.99241, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00726, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.99241, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00726, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.99329, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00671, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.99329, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00671, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  52.083333% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.99447, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00529, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.99447, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00529, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  54.166667% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.99577, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00346, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.99577, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00346, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  56.25% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.99705, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0016, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.99705, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0016, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  58.333333% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.99822, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.99822, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  60.416667% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.99921, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99884, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.99921, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99884, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  62.5% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99816, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99816, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  64.583333% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.00057, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99795, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.00057, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99795, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  66.666667% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.00095, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99811, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.00095, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99811, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  68.75% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.00114, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99851, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.00114, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99851, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  70.833333% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.00119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99903, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.00119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99903, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  72.916667% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.00114, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99955, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.00114, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99955, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.001, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.001, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  77.083333% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.00083, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00033, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.00083, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00033, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  79.166667% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.00063, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00052, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.00063, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00052, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  81.25% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.00044, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00058, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.00044, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00058, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  83.333333% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.00027, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00053, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.00027, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00053, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  85.416667% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.00012, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00042, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1.00012, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00042, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  87.5% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00027, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00027, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  89.583333% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.99991, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00013, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.99991, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.00013, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  91.666667% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.99986, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.99986, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  93.75% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.99983, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99991, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.99983, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99991, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  95.833333% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.99982, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99985, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.99982, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99985, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  97.916667% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.99983, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99984, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(0.99983, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.99984, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Show</button>
```

Comment: Why it doesn't work when I add it to the image tag? Actually I'm applying the animation only to the image tag. I don't wanted it to be applied to the div.